# Factorise of polynomial

Tags: polynomials

Factorize

$$x^4 - 5x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 6$$

I have tried different methods to solve but could no be able to do so. Please can somebody help.
Your individual contributions would be greatly appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Inspection could be a good idea.

Comment: Factor over which ring or field?

Comment: Hint: $6 =5+1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Use the rational root theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$$x^4 - 5x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 6=x^4-5(x^3+x^2+x+1)-1
\\=(x-1)(x^3+x^2+x+1)-5(x^3+x^2+x+1)$$

and $$x^3+x^2+x+1=(x+1)(x^2+1).$$

Answer (score 0):

Obvioulsy, $x=-1$ and $x=6$ are roots, so that we obtain
$$
x^4 - 5x^3 - 5x^2 - 5x - 6=(x^2+1)(x+1)(x-6)
$$
in $\Bbb Q[x]$.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check for some solutions and then factorize the polynomial. For instance, if you set $x=-1$, then $P(-1)=1+5-5+5-6=0$, so $x=-1$ is one of the roots.

Now, you can divide the polynomial to $x+1$. We have: $$\frac{P(x)}{x+1}=x^3-6x^2+x-6$$
and you can easily see that: 
$$x^3-6x^2+x-6=(x-6)(x^2+1)$$
So:
$$P(x)=(x+1)(x-6)(x^2+1).$$